# Rails 4 polymorphic through assocation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, polymorphic-associations

I am hoping someone can help has I am getting nowhere fast.  I have the following setup, from top down and i will remove an spurious code.  I would like to keep the polymorphic model of prospecting as the rcs_prospecting and ara_prospecting both use field from this model and also have their own fields.

contact.rb

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :ara_prospecting
  has_one :rcs_prospecting

  .... 
end
```

ara_prospecting.rb

```
class AraProspecting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
  has_one :prospecting, as: :prospectable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :prospecting, :reject_if => :all_blank, :update_only => true
end
```

rcs_prospecting.rb

```
class RcsProspecting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
  has_one :prospecting, as: :prospectable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :prospecting, :reject_if => :all_blank, :update_only => true
end
```

prospecting.rb

```
class Prospecting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :prospectable, polymorphic: true 
  belongs_to :user 
end
```

What i am trying to do is create a has_one through association to the user model from the contact model via the ara_prospecting and the rcs_prospecting associations.  Essentially i would like

```
has_one :ara_user, through...(ara_prospecting -> prospecting -> user)
has_one :rcs_user, through...(rcs_prospecting -> prospecting -> user)
```

I have looked at various articles and tried different things, but cannot seem to crack it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `has_one :through` association, I'd remove the `ara_prospecting` and `rcs_prospecting` altogether.

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :prospecting

  .... 
end

class Prospecting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact

  scope :ara, -> {where(category: "ara")}
  scope :rcs, -> {where(category: "rcs")}
end
```

In your `Prospecting` migration, add `t.string :category` and assign them either `ara` or `rcs` when you create the objects. The scopes I defined will let you separate them easily.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  The prospecting model is a polymorphic model that rcs_prospecting and ara_prospecting 'inherit' but each of these models also have their own unique fields.  Not sure if your suggestion will work in this instance?

Comment: Well, if the `rcs` and `ara` models have only a few fields each, you can just move them to the `prospecting` model. Sure, you will always have some `nil` (or maybe blank) values, but it will work. If they have a bunch of fields (say, 6 or more each), combining them might not be the best idea. But either way it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I would like to stick with the method currently as it all works pretty well so far and it is also a good way to learn different techniques.  The association works referencing it via each model, but it would be good to know a way to have a direct relation from the contact model. Thanks again